# How to find a specific AVR header file

Tags: c, include, avr, atmega, atmelstudio

I am rewriting some old code for an ATmega32M1.  I would like to reuse some of this old code.  In one place, the previous author has written:

```cpp
Hard_reset();       // wait for watchdog to timeout
```

This `Hard_reset();` is a macro defined in another file, and does exactly what the comment says:  enable the watchdog and then enter an infinite loop. This included file is `atmegaxxm1c1_drv.h`, and its comments make it look like it is an official Atmel library header written in 2009 by a fellow named jtellier.

So far, no problems.  But this file has been included separately, with an `#include "atmegaxxm1c1_drv.h"` referencing a version of this file that has been copied into the project's master directory.  I'm not a huge expert in these matters, but this looks to me like a device-specific header that *should* be included under another, generic file; like  how I don't need to include `<avr/iom32m1.h>` because `<avr/io.h>` includes it for me.

The problem is, I can't find what that header file is!  I have searched through all the files on my PC, and the only time that file shows up is in this project - I would have expected it to also be included with the other AVR header files.  I have searched for it on the interwebs, and Google manages to find *one (1)* single result - a download from some questionable-looking Chinese website (which, knowing who wrote this code, is probably where it came from initially... ).

My question is:  Where does this file come from?  How is this file *supposed* to be included?

---

Edit:

StackOverflow does not allow attaching files to questions, but I thought it would be helpful to post the introductory comment from the file.  All other documentation within the file is about how the functions within it should be used.

```
//******************************************************************************
//! @file $RCSfile: atmegaxxm1c1_drv.h,v $
//!
//! Copyright (c) 2009 Atmel.
//!
//! Use of this program is subject to Atmel's End User License Agreement.
//! Please read file license.txt for copyright notice.
//!
//! @brief This file gives reference information about the intrinsic
//!        functions of AT9megaxxM1/C1 devices. These functions provide direct
//!        access to low-level processor operations.
//!
//! This file has been validated with:
//!     - AVRStudio 4.15.623,
//!     - IAR C/C++ Compiler for AVR 5.20.1 (5.20.1.50092)
//!
//! @version $Revision: 3.00 $ $Name: jtellier $
//!
//! @todo
//! @bug
//******************************************************************************
```

Comment: I've found the Chinese site that you mentioned, the file itself is just a few macro definitions, but the file is part of AVR076.zip which is [Atmel's AVR CAN - 4k Bootloader](http://professordan.com/avr/techlib/techlib8/appnotes/pdf_avr/AVR076.pdf). BTW, the Chinese site has the file name as `atmegaxxm1c1_drv.h.svn-base` .svn-base file is sort of a cache file created by Subversion version control software, so it looks like someone copied it out from a PC which has the Subversion installed, that at least is the case for the Chinese copy.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: How is this file *supposed* to be included?

Read the documentation in that file, or the documentation of the file including it.

- There is no file named `atmegaxxm1c1_drv.h` in [AVR-LibC](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html), neither amongst the official interface, nor amongst the headers used internally in AVR-LibC.
- There is no file named `atmegaxxm1c1_drv.h` in [avr-gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=tree;f=gcc/config/avr;hb=HEAD) nor in [libgcc for AVR](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=tree;f=libgcc/config/avr;hb=HEAD).

So the only information we have is the file name.

> a device-specific header that should be included under another, generic file like `<avr/io.h>`.

No. That file is not part of AVR-LibC.  While you can hack anything into your local copy of AVR-LibC, nobody would do that.

Technically, there are three ways to include a file:

1. `#include "file.h"` for ordinary headers.
2. `#include <file.h>` for system headers.
3. By means of gcc command line option [`-include file.h`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-include).

where the search path can be extended by means of `-I path` for a path containing ordinary headers, and by means of `-isystem path` for a path containing system headers.

Comment: Hmm.  I was sure it must be part of AVR-libC somewhere because of its copyright.  I asked this question because what the previous code was doing felt a lot like hacking the local AVR-LibC.  The existing code has no comment on why this file is included.   

Is there some way I can attach the `atmegaxxm1c1_drv.h` file to this question, if that would help?

Comment: You can add it in code tags (3 backticks before and after the code). If the code is too big, maybe make a pointer to https://godbolt.org/ or https://pastebin.com/ It's already clear it's not AVR-LibC from the used naming convention. As it appears, the file is from Atmel and not part of AVR-LibC.